# Paypal IPN $_GET Transaction Id back to success return url

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I'm trying to make my paypal ipn return to the url with a GET of status with a value of the user paypal transaction id.

An example is `<input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://example.com/products.php?status=<?php echo $txn_id; ?>">`

I want it to get the transaction id from the payment they just payed.
I have a system that checks everything else, once the transaction id is in the url.

I'm just not sure how to make it get the transaction id in to the URL.

I need to do this on my paypal return form variable so they get redirected back to the page with their transaction id.

This is a different page from my IPN page.

How could I go about doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to turn on PDT

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45671366/paypal-buynow-get-instead-of-post-with-params-for-returnurl)

[and tutorial here](https://www.codexworld.com/paypal-standard-payment-gateway-integration-php/comment-page-2/#comment-49244)