# Paypal BuyNow - GET instead of POST with params for returnUrl

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I´m running into an issue that I detected today. I have the following paypal button config :

```html
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" i d="paypalFormId">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="mybusinessID">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="MyProductName">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="1.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="somecustom infos needed in the redirection">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://myreturnurl.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="https://mycancelurl.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="myIPNUrl">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <div class="row">
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit-next pull-right">Bestellung abschließen</button>
    </div>
```

I didn´t change anything that could impact this code in the last days, nevertheless, redirection POST parameters are missing and redirection is a GET now and not a POST method anymore, even with the rm=2 !

Any idea, what´s going on ?

Best regards,

Antoine

**Edited :**

I was able to isolate the issue on JSFiddle : if I remove the item_name input then it works. I have no clue why but maybe it helps you guy telling me what I do wrong !

Comment: I experience similar issue in my code. The same source code worked perfectly a few days ago. I guess this is a global system issue in PayPal.

Comment: This is possibly caused by the same global issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45686395/dont-get-any-from-paypal-simulator-ipn-post-data-in-zend-framework-2

Comment: Hey Koala, on my side, it´s not an IPN issue, it´s the "return" page.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue.  Did anyone get a resolution?  For now I am using the steps mentioned in the below - to use PDT, but it is very annoying that PayPal have no notice about this sudden change, and if it's an error or not, there is nothing notified anywhere about it.

Comment: There is this notice that I have found, but there's no mention of any removal of POST data in return URL:  https://www.paypal-knowledge.com/infocenter/index?page=content&id=FAQ2067

Comment: Hi @AntoineVerger, I am facing the same issue (https://stackoverflow.com/q/46277329/3286487). Any progress? I removed item_name input with the same result (GET).

Comment: Didn´t find a good solution. Official feedback from Paypal was to switch from IPN to the PDT method ...

Answer (score 2):

We had the same problem.
You need to enable "PDT", then the custom field will be returned in the "cm" variable of the return url post.

"Auto Return" also needs to be enabled to use "PDT", but you can still set the return URL in the button form post instead of in the "Auto Return" config if you need it to be dynamic.

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/payment-data-transfer/

Try out this sandbox pay button and see what the response looks like when it is recorded on our return URL.

```html
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick"><input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.67">
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://test.smsportal.co.za/onlinePaymentv2/Testing3rdPartyResponse.aspx"> 
<input type="hidden" name="custom" value="this is the custom variable. it is named 'cm' in the returned Url."> 
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://test.smsportal.co.za/onlinePaymentv2/Testing3rdPartyResponse.aspx"> 
<input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2"> 
<input type="hidden" name="cbt" value="Return to Merchant"> <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypalmerchant@smsportal.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Credit Purchase">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
<input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services"><input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Pay now"><img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"></form>
```

Comment: Thanks Cornelius, I will try this out !

Comment: I tried it out Cornelius. Activated PDT, deactivated IPN and still no POST but a GET. I´m also in touch with Paypal Support team but they are helpless so far ....

Comment: Paypal support isn't great.
I ignored the method type and just looked for the variables in the request.

Comment: I added a button to the answer so you can see the variables the return Url should deliver.

Comment: So now the return URL is full of the variables e.g. success.php?amt=300.00&cc=USD&etc.... is there a method to hide these parameters?