# Paypal return with POST method

Tags: html, http, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to test a Paypal third-party shopping cart button with a sandbox account. The button looks like this:

```html
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top" id="<some_id>">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="<sandbox_account_email>">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="DE">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_1" value="item_number_1_value">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="item_name_1_value" id="paypal-order-name">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="10" id="paypal-last-amount">

    <input type="hidden" name="item_number_2" value="item_number_2_value">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="item_name_2_value">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="45">

    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="0">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="rm" value="2">
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynow_SM.gif:NonHostedGuest">
    <input type="image" id="order-pay-with-paypal" src="/files/1414/1874/7188/checkout-logo-large-de.png" intent="" in-highres-src="/files/9214/1874/7188/checkout-logo-large-de-2x.png" border="0" name="submit" disabled="true">

    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="https://somewheretoreturn.com/orders">
    <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8">
</form>
```

The payment is done successfully, and the redirection occurs, but as a `GET` method. I need the redirect to my website be a `POST`. The `rm` variable is set to `2`, as described in [documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/), what else do I need to set to do a `POST` request?